# How to add unit test for C++ in VS 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I know I can use gtest and other frameworks but I am looking if there is built in solution.

Also please note that I would like to avoid any modifications to my project.

By this I mean that my project is main that uses some .h/.cpp pairs (or just .h in case of templated headers) and I would like to test the implementation of that code without making my project a shared library.

So ideally my current project would go from:

> my_class.cpp
>
> my_class.h
>
> my_template_class.h
>
> main.cpp // includes my_template_class.h and my_class_a.h

to

> my_class.cpp
>
> my_class.h
>
> my_class_test.cpp
>
> my_template_class.h
>
> my_template_class_test.cpp
>
> main.cpp // includes my_template_class.h and my_class_a.h, no changes compared to before

I know that tests run as "main" and that main needs to exist, but I hope VS is smart enough to generate boilerplate code for me (main that includes my_class_test.cpp and then runs the tests from it).

Also if you consider linking old documentation please note that it does not work for me in VS 2017( step

> In Solution Explorer, in the shortcut menu of the project, choose Add,
> New Item, and then choose C++ Unit Test.

does not work for me, I have no C++ Unit Test offered).

Comment: Actually VS C++ Unit Test projects are compiled into dll and do not require "main". Please provide a screenshot of your "New project" dialog. Typically C++ unit test project template can be found at `Visual C++` -> `Test` -> `Native Unit Test`.

Comment: I do not want to create new project, just add tests to existing project.

Comment: VS C++ Unit Test is a separate project type, you can not just add it into existing project.

Comment: Well, that sucks... You can make that comment into answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: [C++ VS 2017 write unit tests in the same project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-microsoft-test-framework-for-cpp?view=vs-2017#same_project)

I found the link above here: [C++ Unit Testing in Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/19/cpp-testing-in-visual-studio/). Which has some useful links at the end too.